# Authenticating to SharePoint from fiddler/postman fails with 401

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api, authentication, postman

I am trying to follow the guidance in many articles, one by Fabian williams, on how to make queries from Fiddler or Postman, but I keep getting 401 unauthorized. I have **SharePoint on prem 2016**, with Feature pack 2.

I am trying to make a post request, to a url that looks like this:

> http://devserver/sites/hr/_api/contextinfo

in Postman, I added the authorization as basic auth, with my username and password, which added the Authorization header for me, and `Accept: application/json;odata=verbose;`

When I try to make the request, I get 401 unauthorized.

*Here's how my request looks like in Postman:*

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use NTLM as your auth mechanism.

Comment: I tried to do that, didn't work.

Comment: @TrevorSeward do I need to be signed in with the same user I have access to in SharePoint? For example, I am signed to my computer with a local user, but connecting to sharepoint with a domain user.

Comment: With Postman, you can pass arbitrary credentials. But you should make sure your username is just the sAMAccountName and the Domain box is filled with your domain's FQDN (e.g. corp.example.com).

Comment: @TrevorSeward I tried that, it doesn't work. I saw some examples requiring me to do a POST request to the contextapi end point in order to generate access token, but that request itself isn't authorized. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to use BearerToken from authentication request to the Data request.

By authentication to the `login.microsoftonline.com/company.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token` URL address, you will get a bearer token (you need to fill body with user_credentials). This bearer token will be used in the data request.

- Look at [Postman examples about authentication](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization/)
- [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785592/bearer-token-in-postman/49786588)
- [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709944/sending-jwt-token-in-the-headers-with-postman)

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say "from authentication request" do you mean the POST request to the contextapi? Any request I try to make to sharepoint will generate a 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: Hi authentication to this URL address, you will get bearer token https://login.microsoftonline.com/company.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token (you need to fill body with user_credentials. This bearer token use in the data request.

Comment: I used it for accessing GraphApi, but I think it will works the same

Comment: I am using SharePoint server 2016

Comment: ok sorry I looked on tags and SP2016 wasnt here. Here is nice answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236286/sharepoint-online-rest-api-authentication-in-postman

Comment: That post describes the case with sharepoint online and using Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Within Fiddler is an option to "Automatically Authenticate" and it works beautifully.

You'll still have to call the contextinfo and copy and paste the digest into your call using the `X-RequestDigest` header

[image]