# Getting Items in Postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, postman

I used the instructions [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236286/sharepoint-online-rest-api-authentication-in-postman) to get access to my SharePoint on O365 and I am able to get all kind of information accept some Lists Items. I just get  "value": [] no errors. I know for a fact the list has many items.
Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure to have right permission? Can you post your REST call?

Comment: https://galod.sharepoint.com/sites/Freeze-Demo/_api/Web/Lists gives me all the lists. But https://galod.sharepoint.com/sites/Freeze-Demo/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Names List')/Items gives  "value": []  and I see many items on the site. I may have creates the application in Azure NOT as a user