# Azure Sharepoint Application API Key generation

Tags: permissions, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api

### Introduction

I'm not a Sharepoint developer. I'm attempting to build an API from a php application to talk to the file storage within a Sharepoint site. From what I can The RESTful API makes the most sense to use from what we can see.

I've arranged for Sharepoint/Office365 installation, and have set up a Sharepoint site. I've uploaded a file. Now i'd like to expose this using the restful API.

My understanding is that to do this, the an Azure Application must be created and this Application then offers access to the site.

I've been following the tutorial below:
[SharePoint Online REST API Authentication In POSTMAN](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236286/sharepoint-online-rest-api-authentication-in-postman)

However, there is an issue that I cannot get past. It seems a permissions issue. SO:

### Question

Following the aforementioned tutorial:

1) I have created a registered app in Azure

2) Within required permissions, I have attempted to add API access

Issue:

`SharePoint Online` is not an option, and most Sharepoint Options are greyed out.
I assume `SharePoint Online CLient`, which is present is the desired choice. This is greyed out.

The only available SharePoint option is `Sharepoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principle`.

Given that the intended option is missing, wow do I find/enable the correct option?

I am the site owner, and only email account associated with the whole sharepoint/office365 installation.

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure App you have created, you need to select API  as - Office 365 SharePoint Online.
In the Delegated Permissions section select "Read and Write User Files".
Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

See this MS learn page. When connecting to SharePoint api you need to use a certificate. This example creates a .NET core app. But configuring the Azure AD app is the same for every code base you want to use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins-modernize/from-acs-to-aad-apps#consuming-sharepoint-online-in-app-only-mode-via-an-azure-ad-registered-application