# Connect to Sharepoint online REST API using CURL

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, ntlm, curl

I'm have created a survey in my company sharepoint online site. The response is collected in a list. I want to extract the data from this list by sending a CURL request from another server to REST API for further processing. 
The site URL goes like this: https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ABCD.
I can access the list using this endpoint in browser: https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ABCD/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(title)/items

While trying to access the API through CURL, I am getting an error saying unauthorizedAccessException. HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden error.

```
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</m:message>
```

Below is the curl request:

```
curl "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ABCD/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(title)/items" -v --ntlm --negotiate -u domain\\email_address
```

Can someone please explain what is the issue with this request or is this the correct way to send API request.
Some forums I read say that I may need to generate access_key using an APP ID. But I dont know how to do that.

Any help on this is deeply appreciated. I am a newbie to sharepoint.

Comment: have a look at https://medium.com/@joy.blanks/frontend-frameworks-inside-microsoft-sharepoint-e7694aa43c5d

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to have valid **Client Id** and **Client Secret**. You could get it following **Sharepoint's part** in [Postman related answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/281249/88705)  .

### Curl's part:

I've created a bash script for this. It requires changing of three parameters: `YourTenant`, `client_id` and `client_secret`

```
$ nano ~/get_api_response.sh
```

Paste the next content to it, changing `YourTenant`, `client_id`, `client_secret` to your own values (you could get in Sharepoint's part below).

```
wwwauthenticate=$(curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer" -s "https://YourTenant.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc/" | grep -i "www-authenticate")
bearer_realm=$(echo $wwwauthenticate | awk -F"," '{print $1}' | awk -F"=" '{print $2}' | tr -d '"')
app_id=$(echo $wwwauthenticate | awk -F"," '{print $2}' | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'  | tr -d '"')

grant_type="grant_type=client_credentials"
cl_id="client_id=c2xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx@$bearer_realm"
cl_secret="client_secret=3zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
res="resource=$app_id/YourTenant.sharepoint.com@$bearer_realm"
url="https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/$bearer_realm/tokens/OAuth/2"
content_type="Conent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

access_token=$(curl -X POST -H $content_type --data-urlencode $grant_type --data-urlencode $cl_id --data-urlencode $cl_secret --data-urlencode $res -s $url | awk -F":" '{print $NF}' | tr -d '"}')
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" -H "Accept: application/json;odata=verbose" -s "$1"
```

Apply proper permissions: `chmod 700 get_api_response.sh`

**You could use `curl` with that token the next way:**

```
~/get_api_response.sh "https://YourTenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web"`
```

[Here's slightly different solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219708/10854998)

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X GET --ntlm -u <email>:<password>  https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/<URL>
```

This worked for me and trigger the page contents.