# SharePoint Online authentication with external Angular 8 web application

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

I've an external web application made with Angular 8 where I should display some data coming from our SharePoint Online site.

I've created an user without license that has read-only permissions on a SharePoint list. This user has to be used for authentication from the external Angular web application.

Is there a way to call SharePoint web services from an external Angular application? I don't need authentication for users that use the external application, because I'll provide the user described above.

I've found this Angular service: https://github.com/keriackus/angularjs-sharepoint-authentication but it seems to be for an old Angular version.

Answer (score 0):

If its an external application I think you need to register it in Azure AD

This question may help: [SharePoint Online REST API Authentication](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236286/sharepoint-online-rest-api-authentication-in-postman)

When you have registered your app you will be able to use the access token to authenticate SharePoint requests in your application

Comment: Ok. From examples I've seen so far, using this method should prompt an authentication popup where user insert its credentials. Do you think is possible to override this and force credentials I've already created?